# problem with setInteractive function in phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework

I have recently started using version 3.18 for a game which was earlier developed in version 3.9. Also, I am using Phaser.SCALE.FIT in config.

But on clicking or touching(in case of mobile) on some button images on the canvas nothing happens. I am using `gameObject.setInteractive()` and then `gameObject.on(‘pointerdown’, function(){})` but the pointer down is not detected.

But if the size of the browser window changes somehow in between the game then the click is detected and everything else works fine.

How can I fix this issue any suggestion will be great help.

Comment: In the docs nothings else is said about this problem https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/touchevents/ it looks that you've coded it well, what is strange is that you have to change the size of the window to see it working, so my question is how did you coded it for mobile ? Cordova, Android native, simple navigatior like chrome on smartphone, ... ?

Comment: In phaser, I am checking if the device is a touch device by using 'isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement; ' and I am also using media queries in CSS for different screens. There is a parent div of the game canvas whose size changes depending on the size of the device.

Comment: There is maybe this clue about the scaling to follow, can you please share some code in codepen.io for example

Comment: Thank you. I have posted some parts of the code and images here https://phaser.discourse.group/t/problem-with-setinteractive-function/3261/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know the exact problem but when I used scene.scale.setGameSize(width, height) (https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/scalemanager/#events) in the create() the game starts working properly.